handling line chart overlaps
I’m working on a chart in Vega-Lite with hundreds of lines, and I’m struggling with overlapping lines when their values are similar. This makes the visualization hard to read and interpret.
To address this, I’ve tried an approach where I:
a)Created a rank based on the group ID.
b)Adjusted the y-axis using a calculation: value + (rank * factor) to offset the lines.
While this helps to some extent, the chart still becomes cluttered due to the sheer number of lines.
I would like to ask:

What techniques do you use to offset lines or reduce overlap in such cases?
Any tips for improving readability in dense line charts?

I’d love to hear about your strategies or any tips that have worked well for you.
Sample:
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"month": "1", "value": 1, "group": 1},
      {"month": "3", "value": 6, "group": 1},
      {"month": "1", "value": 1, "group": 2},
      {"month": "3", "value": 6, "group": 2},
      {"month": "1", "value": 1, "group": 3},
      {"month": "2", "value": 3, "group": 3},
      {"month": "1", "value": 1, "group": 4},
      {"month": "3", "value": 5, "group": 4},
      {"month": "2", "value": 1, "group": 5},
      {"month": "3", "value": 6, "group": 5},
      {"month": "2", "value": 1, "group": 6},
      {"month": "3", "value": 6, "group": 6},
      {"month": "2", "value": 1, "group": 7},
      {"month": "4", "value": 3, "group": 7},
      {"month": "3", "value": 1, "group": 8},
      {"month": "5", "value": 5, "group": 8}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "window": [
            {
              "op": "dense_rank",
              "as": "group_rank"
            }
          ],
          "sort": [
            {
              "field": "group",
              "order": "ascending"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "calculate": "datum.value + datum.group_rank * 0.1",
          "as": "adjusted_y_axis_value"
        }
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "interpolate": "monotone"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "month",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "axis": {
            "labelAngle": 0
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "adjusted_y_axis_value",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "group",
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

Thank you very much!
